# Captain Starshield Boots are gone, do I still own them?

Tags: ratchet-and-clank-rift-apart

I collected *Captain Starshield Boots* from

> the Pocket dimension in Ardonis

but I died right after and they disappeared from my inventory. Apparently this is a known bug, and the suggested solution is to reload a previous save. Which I can't, since I've just completed the game and I was trying to figure out why those boots were missing...

It's not a big deal, they are not required to get the Platinum, but they may be useful because completing the set gives a +20% exp bonus, which is pretty nifty in order to max out every weapon. Also because I DID collect them!

So a couple of questions:

- do I still receive that bonus, even if the boots are not visible in my inventory?
- if not, will I be able to collect them again while playing New Game+?